# Get photo reference

Tags: android, android-studio, google-places-api

I am trying to find a way to obtain photo reference string from google places api. This is the format of google:

```
 "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 768,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/114756359878708427597/photos\"\u003eHotel Olympic\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRdAAAAGWSabKG9f1wwRa1-dg0RVlb_m54RQDO023QTxEgOdFvlE2KjnK9Saxiqnxanr0yTCdbEg183RUk0kncFVwmFoQ8kn5yjnPHGZ-3-vi8Jck-6MbfJLU__h7hibPJ4tko3EhAhSR1B_4-eT4c6A_s_32I_GhTFiO19eMhOD5x5xYfB4DN3ABOtKA",
               "width" : 1024
            }
         ]
```

How can i get the photo reference string? Is there a way to get just that or do i have to do something else?

This is my java code:

```
private HashMap<String, String> getPlace(JSONObject jPlace){
    HashMap<String, String> place = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String photo_reference= "-NA-";
        if(!jPlace.isNull("photos")){
            //something to do here
        }
        //a string builder here to create the url
        place.put("photo", theUrl);
}
```

where jPlace is a place from google places api in JSONObject format

Ofcource there is more code but i just uploaded the part where i get the jsonObject

Comment: you only have to parse that json string than you will get photo_reference string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is what i had to do in `//do somethign here` part:

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=50&photoreference=");

        JSONArray photos = jPlace.getJSONArray("photos");

        //Run for loop for getting photo_reference string in each object

        for (int i=0; i <= photos.length; i++){
          JSONObject getPhtotos = photos.getJSONObject(i);
          String photo_reference = getPhtotos.getString("photo_reference");
          sb.append(photo_reference);
          sb.append("&key=...");
        }
```